# Conda Environment duplication without downloading python

Tags: batch-file, yaml, anaconda

I did a GUI application and my companny does not allow me to use .exe . Therefore, I have sent the project to shared folder and I created a .bat file to go that path and write python main.py. Hoewever, I need to make sure that everyone has the exact same environments as mine, I exported my env list as a .yml file but when I try to read it in my collegues computer, admin permission comes when it tries to download python (note that no one has python on their cmd, we use anaconda's python)
What do you guys recommend for me.

created bat file to import .yml file as an environment.